# TortoiseHg for Windows: How to push to Google Code?

Tags: tortoisehg, google-code

I created a project with Google Code, checked it out from *https://stackexchange.googlecode.com/hg/* using the TortoiseHg shell extension in Windows. Then I committed a new file to the local repository and I wanted to push my changes to Google Code. It asks me for my username and password and I give it my Google login (@gmail.com) and password and I get an *abort: authorization failed* error.

What should I use for username and password when pushing from TortoiseHg to Google Code? Or am I just "doing it wrong"?

**Update:** I forgot to mention, my password contains lower and upper-case letters, digits and various punctuation characters. I have tried escaping all the punctuation using `%%2E` as the [Google Code MercurialFAQ](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/MercurialFAQ) suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to use my Google account password instead of the Google Code password generated by https://code.google.com/hosting/settings